# How to get data from another table using ID from another table

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to get a data from a table to another table using it's primary key.

```
products_table:
id   name    type_id  date_added
 1   item1      2        1234
 2   item2      2        5678
 3   item3      1        0000

product_type_table:
id  type_name
 1    type1
 2    type2
 3    type3
```

I am querying the first table using this code:

```
Products::select('name','type_id')->where('id',$id)->get()
```

Now, how do I automatically get the type_name from the product_type_table using the type_id from the products_table?

Comment: Take a look at [laravel joins doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins)

Comment: make relation and use method with()

Comment: Eloquent tutorials should be helpfull to you, rtm

Answer (score 0):

As Jack Skeletron pointed out, the Laravel documentation has [examples for joining 2 or multiple tables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins).

In your case

```
$products = DB::table('products_table')
    ->join('product_type_table', 'products_table.type_id', '=', 'product_type_table.type_id')
    ->select('products_table.name, products_table.type_id')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use left join.

```
DB::table('product_type_table')
        ->leftJoin('products_table', 'product_type_table.id', '=', 'products_table.type_id ')->where('product_type_table.id',$id)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Product Model add Below code for joining 2 tables:

```
use App\Models\ProductType;

public function type()
{
 return $this->belongsTo(ProductType::class);
}
```

and change the line:

```
Products::select('name','type_id')->where('id',$id)->get()
```

to

```
Products::select('name','type_id')->with(['type' => function($q){
    return $q->select('type_name');
}])->where('id',$id)->get()
```

Hope this works for you.